# Is there a way to change an iPhone’s User-Agent string?

Tags: iphone, ios, network

I’ve been getting page errors on a variety of sites when using both safari and edge browsers.  This one came from my school account when I was trying to open a different page and was dumped out:

> •   Activity ID: 00000000-0000-0000-7e3f-0180000400db
> •   Error time: Tue, 29 May 2018 14:42:18 GMT
> •   Cookie: enabled
> •   User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1

I also got Disallowed Provider Error when trying to connect to my Azure account for school.

> The operation is not permitted for namespace 'Microsoft.Storage'. List of permitted provider namespaces is 'Microsoft.Authorization,Microsoft.Features,microsoft.insights,Microsoft.NotificationHubs,Microsoft.Resources,Microsoft.Sql,microsoft.support,microsoft.visualstudio,Microsoft.Web,SuccessBricks.ClearDB'.

Plus, [image: this happened on my fathers computer]

Which leads me to believe that their somehow related. I normally don't use Firefox. I no longer have a Mac.

Is there away to fix this without access to a Mac? I have already replaced the phone and just keeps happening.

Comment: This would appear to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - That is the correct User Agent information for iOS 11.3 Ref: https://deviceatlas.com/blog/mobile-browser-user-agent-strings

Comment: Beautifully started. Allow me to update

Comment: Can you add some details about your actual setup and what are doing to get this error? All we currently know is that something is wrong, but not how you get there

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change your user agent string on iPhone. The user agent string you provided is the standard string that an iPhone uses; nothing out of the ordinary there.

Regardless of this, the mentioned error is not because of the iPhone user agent. The error mentions namespaces for providers, this is regarding the namespaces for the authentication provider that the website single sign on uses. This is something you should contact your administrator about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different web browser.  The paid web browser iCab lets you change the user agent string.

Whether or not your access to the website is blocked because of the namespace issue mentioned by poster grg is beyond the scope of my answer.

It is not uncommon for education sites to have Windows dependencies built in the site.  You may try some of these browsers to get around Windows dependencies.

Puffin

"Puffin Web Browser is a wicked fast Mobile Flash Browser. Once users experience the thrilling speed of Puffin, regular mobile Internet feels like torture. Puffin Free is the free version of the Puffin family and supports Adobe Flash over cloud during "off-peak hours" from 8AM to 4PM (subject to change without prior notice)"
Free:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/puffin-web-browser-free/id472937654?mt=8
Paid:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/puffin-web-browser/id406239138?mt=8

VirtualBrowser for Firefox with Flash-browser, Java Player and Add-ons - iPhone Edition
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/virtualbrowser-for-firefox/id609289360?mt=8

Photon Flash Player for iPad - Flash Video & Games plus Private Web Browser
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photon-flash-player-for-ipad/id430200224?mt=8

"java for iPad is now a reality!
If you were ever wondering how to use java for iPad, now you can! With the Virtual-Browser for Firefox App, java for iPad is possible with one simple app download! Virtual-Browser for Firefox App opens up a wide variety of apps and games – like java for iPad – that you can use from your iPad"
http://www.virtualfirefox.com/java-for-ipad

By Splashtop Inc.
Flash Video Web Browser – Full Chrome, IE, Firefox, Safari Compatible
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flash-video-web-browser-full/id431331485?mt=8

iPad web browsers set to IE:
http://www.macsinlaw.com/make-your-iphone-ipad-surf-like-internet-explorer-or-fi refox/